# Selenium ActionChains works only when displayed

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to use some Selenium scripts to automate the playing of an online game. Since the game is displayed on a HTML5 Canvas I can't interact directly with classic Selenium clicks, but I have to use the ActionChains class. This shouldn't be a problem, in fact it works just fine when displayed on screen, but in the moment I switch to another window and the Chrome is no more displayed the actions stop. I can't make my mind around this, I have no idea why it behaves like that and also online I didn't find anything. Just to specify, the ActionChains methods I use are click(), hold() and release() + perform() to make everything work; I leave an example from my code below:

```
def moveObject(self, piece, startPos): # Drag and drop an object
        startCoordX, startCoordY = self.transformCoordinates(self.getCoordStartPos(startPos))
        endCoordX, endCoordY = self.transformCoordinates(self.getDropPosition(piece))

        self.actions.move_to_element(self.canvas)
        self.actions.move_by_offset(startCoordX, startCoordY)

        self.actions.click_and_hold()

        self.actions.move_to_element(self.canvas)
        self.actions.move_by_offset(endCoordX, endCoordY)

        self.actions.release()

        self.actions.perform()
```

I also post the self.actions declaration just for completeness:

```
self.actions = ActionChains(self.driver, duration = 20)
```

If anyone could help me it would be a big thing, thanks.